# Debian Nvidia driver: black screen without cursor and without tty

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Looks like display can not display anything because Ctrl + Alt + F* do nothing. Display itself works - I see few correct screens before loading of the operating system. I can connect through ssh.

My gpu is GeForce 6600GT.

Debian 9 i386 with all updates.

I did the steps from [Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#stretch-304xx).

Content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
[    35.049] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    35.049] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 i686 Debian
[    35.049] Current Operating System: Linux hdd-debian-monara 4.9.0-3-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2 (2017-06-26) i686
[    35.050] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-686-pae root=UUID=b88e0d72-f111-4b54-a2ee-6dd4d1997873 ro quiet
[    35.050] Build Date: 07 July 2017  06:13:53AM
[    35.050] xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[    35.050] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    35.050]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    35.050] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    35.050] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Aug 13 11:07:10 2017
[    35.050] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    35.051] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    35.051] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    35.051] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    35.051] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    35.052] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    35.052] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    35.052] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    35.052] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    35.052] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    35.052] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    35.052]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.052] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    35.052] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    35.052] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    35.052] (II) Loader magic: 0x802af720
[    35.052] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    35.052]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    35.052]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[    35.052]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    35.052]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    35.054] (--) using VT number 3

[    35.054] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    35.055] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    35.058] (--) PCI:*(0:3:0:0) 10de:0140:1458:3125 rev 162, Mem @ 0xf4000000/67108864, 0xe8000000/134217728, 0xfa000000/16777216, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    35.058] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    35.058] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[    35.114] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    35.114]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.114]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    35.114] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.135  Tue Jan 17 15:15:59 PST 2017
[    35.114] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" to /dev/dri/card0
[    35.114]    loading driver: nvidia
[    35.114] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    35.114] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    35.114] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 2
[    35.114] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 3
[    35.114] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 4
[    35.114] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 5
[    35.114] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 6
[    35.114] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 7
[    35.114] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    35.114] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    35.114] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    35.115] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    35.115]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.115]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.115] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    35.116] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    35.116] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.116]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.13
[    35.116]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.116]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.116] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    35.116] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    35.116] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[    35.116] (II) Unloading nv
[    35.116] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    35.116] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    35.116] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    35.117] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.117]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.19.2
[    35.117]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.117]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.117] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    35.117] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    35.117] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.117]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.4.4
[    35.117]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.117]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.117] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    35.117] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    35.117] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.117]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 2.3.4
[    35.117]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.117]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.117] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  304.135  Tue Jan 17 14:55:47 PST 2017
[    35.117] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    35.117] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Sep 20 00:31:06 2016 -0400
[    35.117] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    35.117]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    35.117]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    35.117]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    35.117]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    35.117]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    35.117]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    35.117]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    35.117]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    35.117]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    35.117]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    35.117]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    35.117]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    35.117]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    35.117] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    35.117] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    35.117] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    35.118] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    35.118] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    35.118] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    35.118] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.118]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.118]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    35.118] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    35.118] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    35.118] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    35.118] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.118]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.118]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    35.119] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    35.119] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    35.119] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    35.119] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    35.119] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    35.119] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    35.119] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    35.119] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    35.119] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.119]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 0.0.2
[    35.119]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.119] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    35.119] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    35.119] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    35.119] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    35.119] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    35.119] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    35.119] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    35.119] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    35.632] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (ViewSonic VA2213w (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[    35.632] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[    35.635] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce 6600 GT (NV43) at PCI:3:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 131072 kBytes
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 05.43.02.72.00
[    35.635] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce 6600 GT at PCI:3:0:0
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0):     ViewSonic VA2213w (CRT-0) (connected)
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-1
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0):     TV-0
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0): ViewSonic VA2213w (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0): TV-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0): TV encoder: Unknown
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: 155.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    35.635] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: Internal Single Link TMDS
[    35.635] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    35.635] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device ViewSonic VA2213w (CRT-0) (Using EDID frequencies
[    35.635] (**) NVIDIA(0):     has been enabled on all display devices.)
[    35.636] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    35.636] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    35.636] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    35.636] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    35.636] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    35.636] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    35.636] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
[    35.638] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to support custom viewPortOut 1920 x 1080 +0 +0
[    35.638] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (101, 101); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    35.638] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    35.638] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    35.638] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    35.639] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    35.639] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    35.639] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    35.639] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    35.639] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    35.639] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    35.639] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    35.639] (II) Unloading vesa
[    35.639] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    35.647] (II) NVIDIA(0): ACPI: failed to connect to the ACPI event daemon; the daemon
[    35.647] (II) NVIDIA(0):     may not be running or the "AcpidSocketPath" X
[    35.647] (II) NVIDIA(0):     configuration option may not be set correctly.  When the
[    35.647] (II) NVIDIA(0):     ACPI event daemon is available, the NVIDIA X driver will
[    35.647] (II) NVIDIA(0):     try to use it to receive ACPI event notifications.  For
[    35.647] (II) NVIDIA(0):     details, please see the "ConnectToAcpid" and
[    35.647] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "AcpidSocketPath" X configuration options in Appendix B: X
[    35.647] (II) NVIDIA(0):     Config Options in the README.
[    35.647] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    35.779] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    35.779] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[    35.779] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    35.779] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    35.780] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    35.780] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    35.780] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    35.780] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    35.780] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    35.780] (--) RandR disabled
[    35.786] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    35.787] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    35.787] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
```

My `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 375.26  (buildd@debian)  Fri Jan 13 02:38:29 UTC 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I hope that I can fix this problem without using `nouveau` because of higher temperature (without proprietary driver).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the more modern iteration of the `nvidia` driver, but if nobody else wants:

From the log, the NVIDIA driver detects a VGA analog monitor on CRT-0, and got the EDID data (i.e., which resolutions and frequencies the monitor supports). However, it does not list the available modes as every other X driver does (though this may be just a quirk of the current NVIDIA driver), and picks an "autoselect" mode. So the driver seems to be happy, but possibly the selected mode is one that the VGA monitor doesn't like for some reason.

Things to try:

1) Replace

```
Driver "nvidia"
```

with

```
Driver "nouveau"
```

in the xorg.conf (just for testing). Restart display manager or reboot. Look at the `Xorg.log`, the `nouveau` driver should at least tell us more details about the EDID data, and which modelines are available.

2) Uninstall `nouveau`, move the `xorg.conf` file out of the way (e.g. into your home directory), restart display manager or reboot. The other X drivers assume reasonable defaults when no `xorg.conf` is present, hopefully the `NVIDIA` driver, does too. Again, look at `Xorg.log` to see if it comes up with valid modelines.

3) If that didn't help, and if the `nouveau` log showed modelines, add a few standard modelines (e.g. 800x600) to `xorg.log` (and switch back to the `NVIDIA` driver), and see if the `NVIDIA` driver can be persuaded to try those instead.

4) If you monitor has a feature where it displays the current horizontal and vertical frequency by pressing buttons on the monitor, this information would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with `apt purge nvidia*` and removing of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and reinstalling of `nouveau` - now I see desktop again. Against higher temperature I enabled back noisy fan.